# Group by state and date with grouping date by months with pandas and parquet files

Tags: pandas, grouping

In my dataset, which is in parquet files,I have different data with set columns. The ones I am interested in are state, ids, and dates. I would like to group the data by state and then count distinct ids per month. However, dates are already in YYYY-MM-DD format, so when I run my query:

```
df.groupby(["state", "date"])["id"].count()
```

My result is count for each date separately for each state.

How could I modify it to iterate through months separately without changing the whole data files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't provide dummy data for testing so you can try:

Firstly ensure that your date column is of type datetime:

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Then:

```
out=df.groupby(['state',pd.Grouper(key='date',freq='m')])['id'].nunique()
```

**OR**

```
out=df.groupby(['state',df.pop('date').dt.floor('m')])['id'].nunique()
```